# How to log system messages from unexpected poweroff

Tags: shutdown, temperature

My laptop powers off unexpectedly sometimes. There is a warning before that happens, the fans start to spin loudly. I can trigger the shutdown by putting the laptop on heavy load, by trying to build lineageOS. However there are other times when the laptop is under low load, for example during boot (either pre or just after log in) when the fans spin up warning me that it is about to shutdown on it's own.

I have installed a package `lm-sensors` to check cpu temperatures but I never saw anything above 80, that would justify the laptop powering off on it's own immediately. The expected behaviour if the cpu is on heavy load is to throttle, right?

**I would like to capture or access whatever relevant system logs, just before the unexpected poweroff so that I can see, after I reboot, what happened and how it was triggered.** The goal is to find out what is the cause of those unexpected power offs. I 'm guessing the kernel or systemd would be creating some logs

I have unscrewed my laptop and used an air blower to remove any dust, even though there wasn't much - so I don't think this is a cooling problem. My laptop uses Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 fully updated, without HWE so 4.15 kernel series. Hardware wise it has an i5-7300hq cpu and an nvidia 1050Ti. The gpu shouldn't matter as I 've been using the laptop on iGPU mode exclusively before this happened, nvidia's drivers are installed though.

**Update:**

I run `journalctl -b -1 -e` and the result was:

```
May 14 00:34:23 shade smartd[900]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 70 to 68
May 14 00:34:36 shade brisk-menu[19830]: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
May 14 00:34:36 shade brisk-menu[19830]: gdk_window_get_origin: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
May 14 00:35:01 shade CRON[25665]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 14 00:35:01 shade CRON[25666]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 14 00:35:01 shade CRON[25665]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

I don't think any of those messages relates to why the laptop shut down on it's own. I also looked at `/var/log/syslog` and the messages there were the same. Does the motherboard's/CPU's firmware store logs anywhere else that may show something when they tell the laptop to shut down?

Comment: Overloading the Intel Graphics is a bad idea. You should be using the Nvidia for demanding tasks. I wonder if that's the reason for the shutdowns...

Comment: The command `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show the last messages logged at the previous boot. Replacing `-b -1` with `-b -2`, `...` will show earlier boots. `journalctl --list-boots` and `man journalctl` are also interesting.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia most likely

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  I don't believe I am overloading the Intel graphics. Building LineageOS is a CPU intensive task. Moreover I was doing it on the laptop for ~6 months while this problem showed up a month or so ago.